# How to edit a TextField from two different sources?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple app written in Compose, which asks the user a question, and they have to provide the answer in a text field. There's also a "hint" button, which when clicked, will populate the text field with the next character of the correct answer.

Let's assume the correct answer here is "**Leonardo da Vinci**".

All is well, until I click the "Hint" button enough times, so that I am hinted with a space, so for example I get `Leonardo` , and then start typing the rest of the answer on the soft keyboard. The hinted characters disappear for some reason!

[image]

This also happens only on my Pixel 5, Android 12 device, **but not** on a Samsung Galaxy S21, Android 11, for example.

I understand that this has to do with the [`composition` property on the `TextFieldValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextFieldValue#composition()), but we're discouraged from editing it it seems.

On the Pixel, I can see that the `composition` changes depending on what part of the phrase is underlined, but on the Samsung, it's always `null`, so even if I wanted to I'm not able to control it reliably across devices :(

Here's the composable (styling omitted):

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldWithHints(correctAnswer: String) {

    var textFieldValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
    }

    Column {
        BasicTextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { newTextFieldValue ->
                textFieldValue = newTextFieldValue
            }
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {
                val currentAnswerLength = textFieldValue.text.length
                val nextCharacterToHint = correctAnswer[max(0, currentAnswerLength)]
                val newAnswer = textFieldValue.text + nextCharacterToHint

                //here's where I update the current answer with a hint
                textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(text = textFieldValue.text + nextCharacterToHint, selection = TextRange(newAnswer.length))
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hint!")
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I'm using a `TextFieldValue` because I need to control the `selection` property as well - which is how you tell the cursor where to go

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, as you're encouraging different behaviour depending on device/OS version, I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) this issue.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov! Raised here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221713738